# Is there any way to know if the system is downloading/uploading something in Fedora 22?

Tags: internet, system-information

I've been experiencing Internet connection issues and I'm pretty sure it's not `Fedora` but I want to know if there is any way I can know whether the  system/any-other-application is uploading/downloading anything in Fedora 22.

I'm interested in getting the total `KiB` that's being downloaded/uploaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sudo yum -y install iptraf && sudo iptraf
```

might be one place to start.